# Specify multiple root elements in Biztalk DocumentSpecName entry

Tags: biztalk

I have one Biztalk receivelocation, which will validate all the *.xml using the XMLReceive pipeline component.

I have already deployed the corresponding schema with multiple root elements referring to those incoming *.xml files.

As those *.xml are with different root elements, how can I specify those root elements in DocumentSpecName inside the XMLReceive pipeline setting?

I can set x.xsd+roota and it is ok to validate xml with "roota" as the root element. However, this setting cannot be used to validate xml with "rootb", "rootc" as the root element.

Therefore, I would like to know how to set the DocumentSpecName to handle multiple root elements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, do you really need to set the Document Schemas/DocumentSpecName properties or can you rely on the automatic schema resolution?

To asnwer your specific question, you can specify multiple schema, multi or single root, at either Designtime (Pipeline Designer) or Runtime (BizTalk Administrator).

At Designtime, it's simply a matter of adding multple schemas to list in the picker dialog.

At Runtime, you enter the list as a Pipe '|' delimited string.

For a multi-root schema, the Type name must have the Root qualifier denoted by the '+'.  For example:
MySchemaClass.MyMultiRootSchemaType+DocType1

Use format for both local and fully qualified names.